# The diophantine equation $y^3=x^2+4$ has only $4$ solutions. Is there an easy proof?

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

Here

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2169360/how-to-determine-the-number-of-solutions-to-the-diophantine-equation#comment4461761_2169360

the equation $$y^3=x^2+4$$ is mentioned which has only the solutions $(\pm2,2)$ and $(\pm11,5)$. I suggested to subtract $8$ and factorize to get $$(y-2)(y^2+2y+4)=(x-2)(x+2)$$

> Can I prove only with modular arithmetic , quadratic residues and similar methods, that there are no more solutions ? Does my approach help ?

Comment: Oops, seems that the question has been deleted.

Comment: Coincidentally, a related question was asked minutes ago: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2170088

Comment: Yes that is my question. Not related to the other post though I am writing up a answer to this question as we speak. I guess someone else from my course is posting here.

Comment: @barto Did not notice. In fact, a coincidence! Do you have an idea ?

Comment: http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/gradnumthy/mordelleqn1.pdf

Comment: Google "Mordell equation".